# low level requirements for ethernet frame in linux

Tags: linux, packet, ethernet, libpcap, winpcap

I'm developing a high-speed, high-resolution video camera for robotics applications. For various reasons I need to adopt gigabit ethernet (1Ge) or 10Ge to interface my cameras to PCs. Either that or I'll need to develop my own PCIe card which I prefer not to do (more work, plus then I'd have to create drivers).

I have two questions that I am not certain about after reading linux documentation.

#1: My desired ethernet frame is:

```
8-byte interpacket pad + sync byte
6-byte MAC address (destination)
6-byte MAC address (source)
2-byte packet length (varies 6KB to 9KB depending on lossless compression)
n-byte image data (number of bytes specified in previous 2-byte field)
4-byte CRC32
```

The question is, will linux accept this packet if the application tell linux to expect AF_PACKETs (assuming applications CAN tell linux this)? It is acceptable if the application that controls the camera (sends packets to it) and receives the image data in packets must run with root privilege.

#2: Which will be faster:

```
A: linux sockets with AF_PACKET protocol
B: libpcap application
```

Speed is crucial, because packets will arrive with little space between them, since each packet contains one horizontal row of pixels in my own lossless compression format (unless I can find a better algorithm that can also be implemented in the FPGA at real time speeds).  There will be a pause between frames, but that is after 1200 or more horizontal rows (ethernet frame packets).

Because the application is robotics, each horizontal row will be immediately decompressed and stored in a simple packed array of RGBA pixels just like OpenGL accepts as textures. So robotics software can immediately inspect each image as the image arrives row by row and possibly react as quickly as inhumanly possible.

The data for the first RGBA pixel in each row immediately follows the last RGBA pixel in the previous row, so at the end of the last horizontal row of pixels the image is complete and ready to transfer to GPUs and/or save to disk. Each horizontal row will be a multiple of 16 pixels, so no "padding" is required.

NOTE: The camera must be directly plugged into the RJ45 jack without routers or other devices between camera and PC.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to change your Ethernet frame format to use the first two bytes after the source and dest MACs as the type, not the length. Old-style lengths must be less than 1536, anything greater is treated as an IEEE type field instead. As you want 6K or more, there's a chance the receiving Ethernet chip / Linux packet handler will discard your frames because they're badly formatted.

As for performance, the Golden Rule is measure, don't guess. Pick the one that is simplest to program and try.

Hope this helps.

Comment: (Actually, it's "less than 1500"; values in the range 1501 to 1535 are not valid at all - I guess 1536 was chosen as the first valid type value because it's 0x0600, on a neat hex boundary.)

Comment: "As you want 6K or more, there's a chance the receiving Ethernet chip / Linux packet handler will discard your frames because they're badly formatted."  Presumably referring to the fact that the Ethernet spec says the maximum frame size is 1518 bytes, including the Ethernet header and FCS; most Ethernet adapters will, as you note, probably discard frames larger than that as bad frames, so you'd have to enable "jumbo frame" support for the adapter (and use an adapter that supports jumbo frames) for this application.

Comment: Why would it be a problem to enable "jumbo frames"?